# Shopware6 APP Flow Manager needs additional Access Rights

Tags: shopware6-app

we use permission setup in our app as tight as possible. Yet, it seems the flow manager is executed using our app permissions. Now all Flows that require additonal permissions we have not acquired in our manifest.xml are not executed correctly and we seem to receive error messages in log file. As an example, we use create state_machine_history in our app.

It now requires me to put
    `<update>mail_template_type</update> <update>document</update> <create>document</create>`

As soon as I extend these permissions to my manifest, the flows are executed smoothly without errors. But my APP is not meant to create any documents, nor do I need sending mails given my business logic.

Is this expected behavior? We are unsure about the process of flow handling in shopware6
We are running Shopware 6.5.1.0 in our test instance.

- tried to be lean as possible on app permissions
- failed to process flow after state_machine_history update of an order